# 0 at the begining of value isnt shown in the output

Tags: c, printf

my question is short, if I have the following 2 lines of code:

```
int var = 01;
printf("%d", var);
```

the output is : 1

how do I get 01 rather than 1?

Comment: Please note that `01` doesn't mean a `1` with a `0` in front, but it means _write 1 using octal base notation_. Thus `010` will print `8`. In general, don't assume that the language works in the way you want, learn how it actually works instead.

Comment: You thought to save the number as a string? If you don't have to use it elsewhere it is probably the most flexible solution

Answer (score 1):

Use left padded format string.

**Solution**

```c
int var = 1;
printf("%02d", var);
```

Comment: can u explain to me plz what is padding?

Comment: padding is add something(in input/output, mostly 0) outer kernel part.

Comment: if i have the value of var = 13, would it still pad 0??

Comment: No, it will print ```13```. because we've specified length to ```2```(in ```%02d```).